# Tomcat Shutdown hook before http protocol handlers are paused

Tags: java, tomcat

Im wondering if there is a way to register a 'shutdown hook' with tomcat that is picked up before the http protocol handlers are paused during the shutdown process.

I have a servlet that reports 'status-ok' back to the load balancer which are set to poll every 5 seconds, my intention is to add a shutdown hook that happens before anything about the application is changed (including transaction managers, spring, tomcat http protocol handlers etc).

The goal is simply to get the servlet to return 'shutting-down' and then pause for 5+ seconds to allow enough time for the load balancer to realise whats about to happen and then let the normal shutdown process occur.

Ive tried ServletContextListener and it seems that tomcat actually pauses the http protocol listener before it gets to me, which means im already too late to be effective.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the doumentation for tomcat through and through, it seems there is no way of achieving this via a shutdown hook.  As a solution to the problem instead, ive decided to create a webservice which is called from our deployment scripts which essentially tells the application that a shutdown is imminent, which triggers the servlet to report to the loadbalancer it is unavailable.  The deployment scripts waits x time before continuing to shutdown the application leaving enough time for the whole thing to happen.

This is slightly more involved and inelegant given that id prefer it to be part of the standard shutdown mechanism, but this does the trick.